# simultaneously download files in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm writing app for android device, which is simple download manager.
I want to download 2/3 files simultaneously, but I'm really confused
how to do it.

I don't want use async task because it could be killed and I want to
run download in background.
So I think I should use IntentService, but I can run only one
IntentService at time.
I have two ideas, how to do it, but I don't know which one to choose.
First is to run intentservice inside AsyncTask and second is to run
thread inside intentservice.
But either ways I don't know how to inform IntentService about new
file to download, while another download is already running.
Or maybe I should use traditional 'implement Runnable'?

I'm writing app for Android 2.2, so I don't have an DownloadManager service :/.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You should use AsyncTask. Thats what you want, if you are going to be downloading huge files it could be an issue, but other than that it should work. I dont see why people would kill what they are downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is exactly what you want if the download happens while an Activity is up. Don't forget though that services can be killed just as as an application. Another option is a service that spawns one thread per download.